# Throwing authentication exception for Http Request

Tags: java, http

I am authenticating credentials for a server http request with the following code,

```
request.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
int rc = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I am catching authentication exceptions like so,

```
catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Authentication", ae);
}
```

Why is it that when I purposefully give invalid credentials, no exception is thrown even when the response code is coming back 401 (invalid credentials). Any ideas folks? I imagine there is a relatively simple explanation for why the exception is not thrown when adding the header.

Comment: I believe it is being handled at some other place

Comment: What HTTP client library is that?

Comment: Not sure why your exception isn't getting thrown bu BasicScheme.authentic(creds, request) is deprecated. See: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme.html#authenticate(org.apache.http.auth.Credentials, org.apache.http.HttpRequest). Use Use ContextAwareAuthScheme.authenticate(Credentials, HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) instead

Comment: @JigarJoshi No error is being caught when I remove my fail safe handling, so although the creds are invalid and response code confirms, nothing is being thrown.

Comment: @fge it is the apache HTTP library

Comment: That Exception doesn't mean what you think it means. You're adding a header to a request before sending it; you're not authenticating anything at that point. If you read the javadoc, it's thrown when: *if authorization string cannot be generated due to an authentication failure*. It's generating the string just fine.